# how to set null when find dupplicate value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have join the table like this

```
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| sales.cus_id |  customers.name      |sales.qty   |sales.price  | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  jamal               |    20      |    26       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  jamal               |    30      |    40       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  jamal               |    25      |    50       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  jamal               |    20      |    38       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 2            |  rakib               |    26      |    39       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 2            |  rakib               |    43      |    21       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

but i want when i find duplicate sales.cus_id then select customers.name as null
like this table.....

```
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| sales.cus_id |  customers.name      |sales.qty   |sales.price  | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  jamal               |    20      |    26       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  null                |    30      |    40       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  null                |    25      |    50       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 1            |  null                |    20      |    38       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 2            |  rakib               |    26      |    39       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
| 2            |  null                |    43      |    21       | 
+--------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do your update in a meaningful and well defined way, there really needs to be another column which provides the *ordering* which you expect.  Assuming say an `id` primary key column exist there, we could try:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET name = NULL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.cus_id = t1.cus_id AND t2.id < t1.id);
```

This would `NULL` out any name for each customer group of records which did *not* have the lowest `id` value.

**Data:**

```
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
| id | cus_id |  customers.name      |   qty      |  price  | 
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
| 1  | 1      |  jamal               |    20      |    26   | 
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
| 2  | 1      |  jamal               |    30      |    40   | 
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
| 3  | 1      |  jamal               |    25      |    50   | 
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
| 4  | 1      |  jamal               |    20      |    38   | 
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
| 5  | 2      |  rakib               |    26      |    39   | 
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
| 6  | 2      |  rakib               |    43      |    21   | 
+----+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+
```

**Edit:**

If you instead want to a select query here, then use:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.cus_id,
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                          WHERE t2.cus_id = t1.cus_id AND t2.id < t1.id)
         THEN t1.name END AS name,
    t1.qty,
    t1.price
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    t1.cus_id,
    t1.id;
```

Comment: i want select customer.name as null when cus_id dupplicate

Comment: @AbdullahalNoman Reload your page and check the updated answer.  I have given a select query you may use here.